# Android - How to pass arguments to DialogInterface onClickListener?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a `RecyclerView` and I want to display a confirmation window before I delete an item.
So I used `DialogInterface.onClickListener` and `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` and now I have a problem because I'm using `ItemTouchHelper` so I can delete with a swipe, and I can't pass the `viewHolder` argument to the `DialogInterface.onClickListener` in order to delete the item.

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    groupViewModel.delete(groupAdapter.getGroupAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                    break;
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(GroupListActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to finish the match?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the parameter final, you can access it within anonymous classes

```
public void onSwiped(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
```

Otherwise, you must sub-class `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` to add a constructor that can accept a ViewHolder as a field

Comment: The Viewholder changes for each item so  it can't be final...

Comment: The parameter to the method can be. Did you try?